# Edit a datetime value in Symfony

Tags: forms, symfony, datetime, twig

I want to save a datetime value, but when I try to render the form, it does not display a date/time picker, just an empty field. If I only use a DateType class, it displays the picker, but not with a DateTimeType. Here's the form:

```
->add('datetimestart', 
                DateTimeType::class, 
                array(
                    'widget'=> 'single_text',

                   "attr" => array
                        ('class' => 'form-control col-7')))
```

Is there a way to show a datetime picker? Or do I have to create a form field for date and another one for time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an html datepicker [more info here](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_form_input_types.asp)

Actually I'm not sure if the Symfomy form engine supports this type natively, but you should be able to create a custom one extending the standard Input class.

Or if you are using a js datepicker, you should trigger that code on the twig template in which you are rendering the form.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up separating both fields: One for date and another one for time. Using the HTML datepicker mentioned by Carlos is better way to do that, but I don't have enough time